# Blink elements in sequence

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, settimeout, setinterval

Good day, all, so i'm doing this thing where i have 4 squares and when i click a button 3 random squares have to blink in different colors in sequence. And i need to store the id's of the squares that blinked in an array. What I can't figure out is how to make them blink one after another. This is what i have so far...https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dmBxYe?editors=0110

```
class App extends React.Component {
constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
        colors: ['yellow', 'red', 'blue', 'green'],
        quantity: 3,
    }
}
start() {
    const {quantity} = this.state;
    const quantityArray = Array.from(Array(quantity));
    const pieces = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.game-piece')); 

    quantityArray.forEach((item, i) => {
      setTimeout(() => {    
        pieces[i].classList.toggle(`${this.state.colors[i]}`);
      }, i * 500); // we're passing x
      setTimeout(() => {
        pieces[i].classList.toggle(`${this.state.colors[i]}`);
      }, 700 * (i))
    });
}
render() {
    return (
        <div className="memory-game">
            {this.state.colors.map((gamePiece, i) => {
                return <div key={`gamePiece-${i}`} className="game-piece"></div>
            })}

            <button onClick={this.start.bind(this)} className="start-game">Start the game</button>
        </div>
    )
}
}

React.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Comment: If you want to initiate one after another, initiate timeout call inside first at the end

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

- Create a looping mechanism based on recursion.
- Accept a callback that will initiate next call and call it inside loop based on condition.

Following is an animate function. It adds class and removes it back after specified time.

It also calls callback if available. So its duty of caller not to pass callback during termination case.

```js
animate(element, className, callback) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    element.classList.toggle(className);
    setTimeout(() => {
      element.classList.toggle(className);
      if (callback) callback();
    }, 200)
  }, 500); // we're passing x
}
```

A simple recursion based loop that calls itself if element and color exists. You can update if condition based on your requirement.

```js
const scheduleAnimation = (i) => {
  const element = pieces[i];
  const color = this.state.colors[i];
  if (element && color) {
    this.animate(element, color, scheduleAnimation.bind(this, ++i));
  }
}
scheduleAnimation(0);
```

**[Updated codepen](https://codepen.io/rajesh_dixit/pen/MGgYRp)**

Comment: Note, this is more of an illustration of how to do it. Hence it does not address any specific conditions like *i click a button 3 random squares*. This is a part OP will have to add on his own

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting thing to solve. Here is what you could do with some help from React setState and JS setTimeouts.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      colors: ["yellow", "red", "blue", "green"],
      quantity: 3,
      output: [],
      currentIndex: -1
    };
  }
  getRandomInt() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(4));
  }
  generateNumbers() {
    const output = [];
    while (output.length !== 3) {
      const generatedNumber = this.getRandomInt();
      if (!output.includes(generatedNumber)) {
        output.push(generatedNumber);
      }
    }

    return output;
  }

  start() {
    const output = this.generateNumbers();
    this.setState({ output: output }, () => {
      output.forEach((item, index) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.setState({ currentIndex: item });
        }, index * 1000);
      });
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="memory-game">
        {this.state.colors.map((gamePiece, i) => {
          let customClass = "";
          if (i === this.state.currentIndex) {
            const css = this.state.colors[this.state.currentIndex]
              ? this.state.colors[this.state.currentIndex]
              : "";
            if (css) {
              customClass = `blink-${css}`;
            }
          }
          return (
            <div
              key={`gamePiece-${i}`}
              className={`game-piece ${customClass}`}
            />
          );
        })}

        <button onClick={this.start.bind(this)} className="start-game">
          Start the game
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#app {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: table;
  background: lightgoldenrodyellow;
}

.memory-game {
  width: 40%;
  margin: 100px auto;
}

.game-piece {
  width: 50%;
  height: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background-color: lightgray;
  &:nth-child(2n + 1) {
    margin-right: 10px;
  }
}

.start-game {
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: red;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

@-webkit-keyframes blinker-red {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    background-color: red;
  }
  50%{
  opacity:1;
  }
  100%{
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes blinker-yellow {
 0% {
    opacity: 0;
    background-color: yellow;
  }
  50%{
  opacity:1;
  }
  100%{
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes blinker-green {
   0% {
    opacity: 0;
    background-color: green;
  }
  50%{
  opacity:1;
  }
  100%{
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes blinker-blue {
   0% {
    opacity: 0;
    background-color: blue;
  }
  50%{
  opacity:1;
  }
  100%{
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

.blink-red {
  text-decoration: blink;
  animation-name: blinker-red;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

.blink-green {
  text-decoration: blink;
  animation-name: blinker-green;
  animation-duration: 1s;
}

.blink-blue {
  text-decoration: blink;
  animation-name: blinker-blue;
  animation-duration: 1s;
}

.blink-yellow {
  text-decoration: blink;
  animation-name: blinker-yellow;
  animation-duration: 1s;
}

.blink-red {
  text-decoration: blink;
  animation-name: blinker-red;
  animation-duration: 1s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```